# Get location of view passed into laravel view composer

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to get the location of a view that is passed into a Laravel view composer?

```
View::composer('*', function($view) {
   // I want to find out the location of the view file here
   // e.g. master.something.header
   // then add this to an array
   $loadedViews = View::share("loadedViews");
   $loadedViews[] = $thisViewName;
});
```

The reason is that I want to have a variable that will be shared between views and contain an array of all the views that are loaded. Any css and js files will be located in directory structure that matches the views one.

This means I can then have a css and js view which then include the required css and js files for the views on the page. All css and js will be directly linked to a specific view.

If there is already a way to do this, or a way to get a list of loaded views, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$view->getName()` was the answer that I wanted.

`$view->getPath()` is the actual path to the file.

Comment: I believe it is actually $view->getName() and $view->getPath().  At least that's what worked for me.  (Laravel 4)

Comment: Yes it is thanks. Was mixing it up with javascript! I've corrected it.