# Laravel 4 View Composer not firing for layout or subview

Tags: view, laravel-4

I'm having trouble getting a View Composer to fire based on a subview.  Specifcally:

```
protected $layout = 'layouts.main';

public function index()
{
    return $this->layout->content = View::make('pages.dashboard');
}
```

pages/dashboard.blade.php contains:

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
    Hello World
@stop
```

Inside layouts/main.blade.php contains:

```
<html>
  <body>
    @include('layouts.partials.header')
    @include('layouts.partials.sidebar')
    @include('layouts.partials.content') // Renders {{ $content }}          
  </body>
</html>
```

My view controller is:

```
View::composer('layouts.auth', function($view)
{
    die("Hit the sweet spot!");
});
```

It will work if I use "pages.dashboard", but not "layouts.main" or "layouts.partials.sidebar".  Any idea how to hook to those views?

Comment: The handler will fire only when `layouts.auth` is rendered.

Comment: Actually, I managed to find that it did fire.  See answer...

Answer (score 4):

Using the tip at [Get location of view passed into laravel view composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943452/get-location-of-view-passed-into-laravel-view-composer?rq=1) for getting a view name, I debugged every view that was called:

```
View::composer('*', function($view) { 
   print $view->getName() . "<br>"; 
});
```

I found that the proper name to listen for is "layouts.partials.sidebar".  Plugged it in and it worked!  Guess it was just a typo on my part the first time.

Comment: Thank you for that tip about getting composer names.  Really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You registered the composer for `layouts.auth` view

```
View::composer('layouts.auth', function($view)
{
    die("Hit the sweet spot!");
});
```

So, it'll work only when `layouts.auth` will be rendered. To hook the composer for `layouts.main` you should register it for `layouts.main` using:

```
View::composer('layouts.main', function($view)
{
    die("Hit the sweet spot!");
});
```

You may also check [this article](http://heera.it/laravel-4-view-composer-master-layout), could be helpful.